# Next steps to take for an apache beam missing class?

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am receiving this error when trying to use apache beam

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/util/DoFnInfo

When trying to run

```
PCollection<ReadableFile> activities = p.apply(
  "ReadBatchFiles", FileIO.match().filepattern("<google cloud storage bucket taken out>"))
.apply(FileIO.readMatches());
```

POM.xml:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

It looks like this was moved at: [link1](https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/f3f325499e33f82eb8873a4e877c56dbc9928043#diff-91792357cc30e1bfcda2e243c3895c0e)

And possibly was at: [link2](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/util)

Any idea how I would link it to the needed location?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google made DataflowJavaSDK compatible with Beam 2.2.0 [only two days ago](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/commit/85508332de85e65e3a694ffea5d6e83186710345), but it has not been released yet. You'll have to wait for the maven release 2.2.0 of the SDK or compile the dependency from source yourself.